# HTML5 Video If hash is equal to value set the audio to 1 else set the audio to 0 using Javascript Functions

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video, hash

Hello I am trying to set the HTML5's video audio level depending on the location hash for example if the hash is #home the video's audio should be 1.0 if the hash isn't #home then the audio level should be 0.0
I've had a play around and i can't seem to get it to work here is my code 
and thank you for taking a look and for any help!

```
 $(function() {
   if (location.hash === "#home") {
     videoAudio();
   }
 } else {
   videoAudioMute();
 });

 function videoAudio() {
   var vid = document.getElementById("myvideo");
   vid.volume = 1.0;
 }

 function videoAudioMute() {
   var vid = document.getElementById("myvideo");
   vid.volume = 0.0;
 }
```

html

```
<div class="background">
      <video id="myvideo" poster="assets/img/slide1-background-img-pattern-01.jpg" controls="" autoplay="" loop=""  >
      <source src="assets/vid/Background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="assets/vid/Background.webm" type="video/webm">
      <source src="assets/vid/Background.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a **syntax error**.

The correct version should be like:

```
$(function () {
        if (location.hash === "#home") {
            videoAudio();
        } else {
            videoAudioMute();
        }
});

function videoAudio() {
    var vid = document.getElementById("myvideo");
    vid.volume = 1.0;
}

function videoAudioMute() {
    var vid = document.getElementById("myvideo");
    vid.volume = 0.0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the spot now its saying Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined: http://i.imgur.com/kDW2c72.png

Comment: Fixed i had to put it blow the JQuery references however it still isn't turning off the volume when the hash is changed and i can see the hash is changed in the console any ideas?

Comment: @ChrisLad try to put  `location.hash == "#home"` instead of `location.hash === "#home"`

Comment: I've decided to do it by class instead and got it to work thank you for the help though much appreciated

Comment: Glad to help you @ChrisLad

Answer (score 0):

To give a proper answer to the question I think we need a little bit more information.

What you can do if you do not want to share more is console log location. This should give you an object with some properties in it. Hash is one of them. Check it and see if you are getting the data that you expect. If hash is not giving what you want you can try using some of the other properties as an identifier, like pathanme.

If the problem is not in the hash but it is in manipulating the audio level you can try jQuery. I have had a lot of headaches manipulating audio and video files with JavaScript but I have found that jQuery work the best.

Hope this helps.